# Creating a custom shader in cocos2d-x shows black screen on android

Tags: android, opengl-es, cocos2d-x, shader

I used a custom shader in my cocos2d-x game to show spotlight effect. it working properly on iPhone but it not working android device. It shows black screen.

I got reference from this link https://github.com/wantnon/2D-lighting

Following is my Sprite subclass

And this is  CmaskedSceneSprite.cpp

```
bool CmaskedSceneSprite::init(Texture2D *texture) {  

    if(Sprite::initWithTexture(texture))
       {
           Size texSize=this->getContentSize();
           //mask shader
           {
               GLchar * fragSource = (GLchar*)FileUtils::getInstance()->getStringFromFile("mask.fsh").c_str();


               GLProgram* pProgram = new GLProgram();
               pProgram->reset();
               pProgram->initWithByteArrays(ccPositionTextureColor_vert, fragSource);
               //bind attribute
               pProgram->bindAttribLocation(GLProgram::ATTRIBUTE_NAME_POSITION, GLProgram::VERTEX_ATTRIB_POSITION);
               pProgram->bindAttribLocation(GLProgram::ATTRIBUTE_NAME_COLOR, GLProgram::VERTEX_ATTRIB_COLOR);
               pProgram->bindAttribLocation(GLProgram::ATTRIBUTE_NAME_TEX_COORD, GLProgram::VERTEX_ATTRIB_TEX_COORD);
               //link  (must after bindAttribute)
               pProgram->link();
               //get cocos2d-x build-in uniforms
               pProgram->updateUniforms();
               //get my own uniforms
               map<string,GLint> myUnifoMap;
               myUnifoMap["texSize"] = glGetUniformLocation(pProgram->getProgram(),"texSize");
               myUnifoMap["r"] = glGetUniformLocation(pProgram->getProgram(),"r");
               myUnifoMap["c"] = glGetUniformLocation(pProgram->getProgram(),"c");
               myUnifoMap["brightColor"] = glGetUniformLocation(pProgram->getProgram(),"brightColor");
               myUnifoMap["darkColor"] = glGetUniformLocation(pProgram->getProgram(),"darkColor");
               //make program
               program.myUnifoMap=myUnifoMap;
               program.setProgram(pProgram);
               //program can be released
               pProgram->release();
               //check gl error
               CHECK_GL_ERROR_DEBUG();
           }           
       }
    return true;
}

void CmaskedSceneSprite::draw(Renderer *renderer, const Mat4& transform, uint32_t flags) {

    //call father draw
    Sprite::draw(renderer,transform, flags);

    Size texSize = this->getContentSize();
    //----change shader

    this->setGLProgram(program.getProgram());
    //ccGLEnable(m_eGLServerState);
    //pass values for cocos2d-x build-in uniforms
    getGLProgram()->use();
    getGLProgram()->setUniformsForBuiltins();

    //pass values for my own uniforms
    float texSize_c[2]={texSize.width,texSize.height};
    glUniform2fv(program.myUnifoMap["texSize"],1,texSize_c);
    glUniform1f(program.myUnifoMap["r"], r);
    float c_c[2]={c.x,c.y};
    glUniform2fv(program.myUnifoMap["c"], 1, c_c);
    glUniform4fv(program.myUnifoMap["brightColor"], 1, brightColor);
    glUniform4fv(program.myUnifoMap["darkColor"], 1, darkColor);
}
```

and this my custom shader program mask.fsh

```
#ifdef GL_ES
precision mediump float;
#endif

varying vec2 v_texCoord;

uniform sampler2D CC_Texture01;

uniform vec2 texSize;
uniform float r;
uniform vec2 c;
uniform vec4 brightColor;
uniform vec4 darkColor;

void main() {
    vec2 texCoord=vec2(v_texCoord.s,1.0-v_texCoord.t);

    vec4 brightColor = max(brightColor,darkColor);
    vec4 darkColor = min(brightColor,darkColor);
    vec2 curPixelPos = vec2(texCoord.s*texSize.x,texCoord.t*texSize.y);//curPixel pos in world space
    float dis_curPixelToC = distance(curPixelPos,c);
    vec4 curPixelColor;
    if(dis_curPixelToC<r){
        //use the curve y=1/(r*r)*x*x-2/r*x+1
        //float temp=max(0.0,1.0-dis_curPixelToC/r);
        //float k=temp*temp;
        //curPixelColor=(brightColor-darkColor)*k+darkColor;

        //use the curve y=x
        curPixelColor=brightColor-(brightColor-darkColor)/r*dis_curPixelToC;
    }else{
        curPixelColor=darkColor;
    }
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(CC_Texture01, texCoord)*curPixelColor;
}
```

Please help me this code working on iPhone. Only on android device it not working.

Answer (score 0):

I got solved my problem of using custom shader in cocos2dx. I moved my shader program to internal shader   folder in cocos2dx library so that it work as internal shader. And in my shader program some non floating variables so i converted that into float. it works for me.